# What type of addressing are these instructions?

Tags: assembly

I have problems to distinguish the instructions.

```
mov [300], bl
mov [bx], cl
```

Comment: I mean, I'm trying to distinguish what type is the ASM instruction. For example mov ax, bx is about registries, ax, [200] is direct

Comment: @OscarFimbres I guess both are "ASM instructions"?

Answer (score 4):

I think `[300]` means "the value stored at address 300. On the other hand, `[bx]` means "the value stored at the address stored in register BX". (Note that neither are constant values, which would just be a naked `300`.)

Comment: +1 Though note that since the data segment is implicitly used it's actually `[ds:300]` and `[ds:bx]` (assuming 16-bit code).

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume

```
bx = 0xF000
bl = 0x00   (duh)
cl = 0x10
```

**Direct addressing**

```
mov byte ptr [300], bl
```

Writes the contents of bl (0) into address 300.

**Indirect addressing**

```
mov byte ptr [bx], cl
```

Writes 0x10 into address 0xF000

**Indirect addressing with direct offset**

```
mov byte ptr[bx+300], cl
```

Writes 0x10 into address 0xF12C *(300 decimal = 12C Hex)*

x86 Has many more addressing modes, see: http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~celio/mc404s2-03/addr_modes/intel_addr.html

To further complicate matters, this explanation is valid for Intel assembler syntax, on AT&T aka GAS syntax, source and destination are reversed.
This should not concern you overmuch because sane people only use Intel syntax, it's much easier to work with.